# how to simplify the integral: $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x t \sin y t}{t-z} dt$ , $z= a+ib, a>0,b>0, x >0 ,y >0$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x t \sin y t}{t-z} dt$$
 where $z= a+ib, a>0,b>0, x >0 ,y >0$.

It is known that:  $ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin{xt} \sin{yt}}{t} dt = \frac{1}{2}\log\lvert\frac{x+y}{x-y}\rvert$ with $ x >0 ,y >0.$ This can be shown by an application of the  Laplace transform.

Comment: 1.) use the multiplication law for sine
2.) express the resulting integrals in terms of Cosine Integral. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineIntegral.html

Ihave the strong feeling that's the best u can do